# How to export every function of a bash script for use with gtkdialog?

Tags: bash, shell, user-interface, export

I have a bash script of the form:

```
cat  << EOF > stackoverflow_source.sh
#!/bin/bash
function f1 () {
         echo This is the first function.
}
function f2 () {
         echo This is the second function.
}
EOF
```

and its GUI with [gtkdialog](http://code.google.com/p/gtkdialog/):

```
$ cat  << EOF > stackoverflow_gui.sh
#! /bin/bash
source stackoverflow_source.sh
export MAIN_DIALOG='
<window window_position="1" title="StackOverflow Question">
 <hbox>
  <button>
   <label>Function One</label>
   <action>f1</action>
  </button>
  <button>
   <label>Function Two</label>
   <action>f2</action>
  </button>
 </hbox>         
</window>'
gtkdialog  --program=MAIN_DIALOG
EOF
```

So after running:

```
$ source stackoverflow_source.sh
```

I get:

```
$ f1
This is the first function.
```

but when I click the corresponding button in the gui (even after sourcing the script) I get

```
sh: f1: command not found
```

When I export the functions with

```
$ export -f f1 && export -f f2
```

they do work in the gui (`sh stackoverflow_gui` and clicking their buttons, echos the text).

Is there a way to export **every** function in my `stackoverflow_source.sh` script? (In my real source script I have hundreds of functions and I do not want to do it one by one).
Alternatively, is there a **better** way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
for func in $(declare -F | cut -f3 -d' ')
do
    export -f $func
done
```

Or, more concisely (but less readable):

```
export -f $(declare -F | cut -f3 -d' ')
```